# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php

I am trying to write a PHP program to compute the number of years, months, and days from a certain date, and am getting an error when I try to get the result:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

The error appears on this line:

```
$values($years, $months, $days) = $c->difference($diff);
```

The full code is:

```
<?php

    class Calculator {

        public $diff = NULL;

        public function calculate ($birthday) {
            $date = date('m/d/y', time());
            $diff = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($birthday));
            return $diff;
        }

        public function difference ($diff) {
            $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
            $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
            $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
            return array($years, $months, $days);
        }

    }


    $c = new Calculator;
    $diff = $c->calculate("11/13/1995");
    $values($years, $months, $days) = $c->difference($diff);
    echo $values[0] . " years, " . $values[1] . " months, " . $values[2] . " days.";

?>
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `$values($years, $months, $days) =` your left hand operand is the result of a variable function call, to which you cannot possibly assign a value (you can only do that with variables and constants, or using special language constructs, like `list`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `list()`:

```
$values($years, $months, $days) = $c->difference($diff);
```

Should be:

```
list($years, $months, $days) = $c->difference($diff);
```

Or to use your current echo, just assign to the array `$values`:

```
$values = $c->difference($diff);
```

It appears you are trying a hybrid of the two.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
$values = $c->difference($diff);
```

And values will hold the returned array.